# Xcode - iTunes Store Operation Failed | An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store

Tags: xcode, itunes, testflight, operation

[Click here to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2rgG.png)

**Fixed this by doing:**

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

Comment: What is the question you want to ask?